# Why do images turn black after previewing them?

Tags: nikon-d7000, rear-lcd

My Nikon D7000 is now 6 months old, all has been well until a few weeks ago, one of two things seem to happen all the time. I take a few shoots and all is OK, then, randomly, I shoot a few more, go to check my LCD Screen and there is no recording of the images just taken, worse, it now won't show me the shots I took earlier which I have already seen.

The second, which its doing now with alarming regularity, it will shoot a few pictures, then I go to shoot again and I can't depress the shoot button(shutter release), the readout says there is no memory card detected, to resolve both these issues, I have to switch the camera off, take out the memory card, put it back in and start again, this morning it was taking no more than 3 or 4 pictures before freezing, I am using genuine Nikon batteries and have just invested in 2, 32GB Sandisk cards, thinking I had a faulty card before, but no!

The worst of this is I have just started shooting weddings, can you imagine the stress of not being able to trust your equipment at such an event!

Comment: You're certainly going to need a backup body (actually backup everything) if you're going to shoot weddings.

Comment: It might be clearer to those who can answer your question (sorry, I don't think I can other than to suggest you take the body back to the shop where you bought it to get them to check it, since it will still be under warranty) to use the same terms they do.   The viewfinder is the thing you look through with your eye to take the shot.  The larger thing on the back of the camera is the screen.

Comment: 1.Please use basic grammar like capitalizing the first word of sentences and the letter "I". 2.You must limit your questions to 1 question per page here. Please open up another topic for the question about "memory card not detected".

Answer (score 1):

This problem might be caused by some sort of setting change that you might not realize you changed. Try resetting your camera to factory settings.